# How can I automate adding members to a Domino Server?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

The company I work for wants to host documents on Lotus Quickr for external vendors to view. The way it currently works is as follows: A project manager needs to retrieve the non-employee's information (name, contact info, job title, etc.), which is sent to the Lotus manager. The Lotus manager then needs to add the non-employee as a new member to the Domino server. Then the Lotus manager needs to send the login credentials to the non-employee. Lastly, the project manager needs to give the non-employee access to the relevant Quickr place.

Because this process is very slow, my manager wants to automate a portion of the process. Our ideal solution would be to build a webpage where the non-employee could fill out their information. The project manager could then look over the the non-employee's information and choose to approve, deny, or send back the information. If the information is approved, the user will automatically be added to the Domino server. Then, the project manager would add them to the Quickr place as usual. This alternative method would eliminate a few steps, a lot of time, and the non-employee's login credentials would only be known to the non-employee.

The problem is that we're not sure how to tackle this. Would it be possible to build an XPage that could be sent out publicly that could handle this? Or is there a similar solution that we could use? I am very new to Domino and Lotus, but I would be comfortable with learning any necessary APIs once I know where to begin. For reference, we are using IBM Notes and Domino Designer 9 Social Edition.

Comment: This question is way too broad. Questions like "What is the best way to achieve this?" or "How can I do that?" are rarely a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Caution! Quickr is EOL. And!!! Quickr has the functionality build in. A room owner (the project manager) can be granted the right to add users to a place that only exist in that place. No need to add them to the Domino directory.

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed possible. Take a look at [the User Group application on OpenNTF](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/LUG%20Template). It includes functionality for users to register themself so that they can login afterwards.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: From what I get they're not really looking at self-registration, they rather would like to simplify their current apply-then-grant-access workflow. Nevertheless the linked project indeed IS interesting, wasn't aware of it, and it might help me with some other current task of mine ;)

Comment: Oh, I agree, Lothar. I linked to that project to help with a solution to the problem with automatically creating users

Answer (score 2):

***in addition*** to @stwissel's and @Thierry's answers:

you of course can build an Xpages based application through which an anonymous user could ask to be granted access to some quickr place. You'll have to keep in mind that most visitors aren't registered users for you Domino server so you need to treat them as anonymous. This could mean that for example resources like company logos or stylesheets used in you "anonymous" application forms need to be marked as `available for public access users`.

Then you'll have to decide how the application forms are passed on to the project manager; you could send the data using mail, which however might open up an unwanted gateway for spammers. Preferably you would store the applicants' data in a small database from which you project managers then pull all open applications.

The rest is simple and has already been layed out by @stwissel und @Thierry: use quickr's ability to maintain its own set of place-based "local" directories (btw. one of the *real* cool features of this otherwise *dead product*).

Speaking about the product: as @stwissel already pointed out this product is no longer maintained by IBM; looking at the long record of known problems quickr had with various browser updates (esp. MSIE), not to speak of future Domino server support allow me to recommend looking for an entirely different solution

Answer (score 1):

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lqwiki.nsf/m_Home.xsp?documentId=F26B114598D21516852577FB005171F4#mobileViewer

QuickR on Domino can allow member not in directory if option is enabled by admin. So no need to ask to lotus manager, project manager can create local member